# How to handle JSON in Dart

Tags: json, dart

I wonder how does Dart handle JSON? More specifically:

1. Can I access item in a JSON object and when, how?
2. Can I convert Darts data structures like  Set and Maps into JSON?
3. Can I create a new JSON, only by calling JSON.parse?
4. How can I add new items into a JSON?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You might find this post of mine interesting:
http://www.grobmeier.de/dart-creating-a-dynamic-list-with-dart-php-and-json-20112011.html

You need to use the JSON package (add json to pubspec.yaml):

```
import 'package:json/json.dart';
```

Here is the according spec:
https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/json.html

To your questions:

1. You can use: List result = JSON.parse( jsonData );
2. With stringify you can turn for example a Map to JSON
3. I am sorry, not sure on this question. You could do: JSON.parse('{key:"value"}')); or something like that
4. You probably need to create a Map out of your JSON with parse, then add your item, and then call stringify

Comment: With recent versions of Dart (e.g. v0.7.x), you should use `dart:convert` library. It provides JSON.decode() and JSON.encode() methods (with better performance). See: http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_convert.html

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [json](https://api.dart.dev/dev/dart-convert/JsonCodec-class.html) property provided by the [dart:convert](https://api.dart.dev/dev/dart-convert/dart-convert-library.html) library.

```dart
import 'dart:convert' show json;

main() {
  var encoded = json.encode([1, 2, { "a": null }]);
  var decoded = json.decode('["foo", { "bar": 499 }]');
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Like Christian, there's also a similar post on my [dartwatch blog](http://dartwatch.com/index.php/2011/11/exploring-dart-sharing-code-between-the-client-and-server/) which might be useful.

Comment: Ah yes, usually I add a reference to this post. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Maybe is this an updated link? http://www.dartlang.org/articles/json-web-service/