# Dartlang: How to get key and values from json?

Tags: json, checkbox, dart

I'm having a little problem and couldn't figure it out. I created a table with checkbox and it's working and can save to json without a problem. Now i wanna make my checkboxes have their default values set from json data when the page loads (to make it easier to edit). Anyway here is my code:

```
//row index
var index = 0;

//gets full info of student
var responseStudent = rpc.call('db.findOne', ['StudentAnket', {
    '_id': '${this.objId}'
  }]);
result = responseStudent['result'];

//gets info needed for my table
//{anket: true, request: true, statement: false, etc...}
var resultMat = result['listmaterial'];

//materials is a list which contains id, name of rows
materials.forEach((m) {

  //creating table body
  index = index + 1;
  tbody.append(new Element.tr()
      ..append(new TableCellElement()..text = index.toString())
      ..append(new TableCellElement()..append(new LabelElement()
              ..text = m['name']
              ..setAttribute('for', m['id'])))
      ..append(new TableCellElement()..append(new InputElement()
              ..id = m['id']
              ..type = "checkbox"
              ..checked = "VALUE TAKEN FROM JSON")));
});
```

So how can i get keys and values from resultMat and set checked property for each checkbox?

Edit:

```
  List materials = [{
  'id': 'anket',
  'name': 'Student anket'
}, {
  'id': 'request',
  'name': 'Request'
}, {
  'id': 'statement',
  'name': 'Statement'
}, {
  'id': 'marklist',
  'name': 'Mark List'
}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your information how your `materials` structure looks like is not clear. A List has only one value not two ('id, 'name of rows'). First you have to ensure that your JSON is not a String but a Dart data structure (Lists, Maps, values).

You can take a look at the answers to this questions to learn how this works 
[Dart Parse JSON into Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24532156)

Then you should be able to access the value like

```
..checked = resultMat[m['id']] ;
```

Comment: How can/should `checked` be derived from this data?

Comment: I won't get keys and values from materials. I have to get them from resultMat which contains json data. So i can check if key = current checkbox.id and if true i would set checked value from this key's value. Materials is just used for creating table.

Comment: Oh... How stupid of me :p. Didn't think it can be obtained with such an easy way. I was only thinking about using loop for each key and check if it's equal to current checkbox's id then set checked value from that key's value :p
Tnx a lot.